Which 2D surface has the largest area in 3D?
Is my thinking correct that the space-filling surface like this one [1] will have the largest area among all surfaces enclosed into a given volume? Or, more exactly, the area of $n$-th approximation to the space-filling surface will have the largest area among surfaces built with 2D segments of the same area and the same minimal distance between the segments? For easier visualization, I looked at the space-filling curve [2].
How to prove or disprove it?
